# xslt removing the duplicate elements

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have the below xml, when xslt is processed want to remove the duplicate elements, there are three policy elements, just want keep single policy  element.

Can anyone give me the xslt for this?

```
<table currency="$" >
    <description>TEST 1</description>
    <methods>
        <method id="36">Day</method>
        <method id="36">R</m>
    </methods>
    <rates tier="amount">
        <rate lower="0.00" upper="1.00">
            <srate method="36">1.00</srate>

        </rate>
        <rate lower="1.10" upper="10.00">
            <srate method="36">10.00</srate>
        </rate>
    </rates>
    <data>
        <policy cid="0">0</policy>
        <policy cid="0">0</policy>
        <policy cid="0">0</policy>
    </data>
</table>
```

Comment: What XSLT have you tried so far, and what output do you want to produce?  What are the rules for deciding whether policy elements are "duplicates" (same `@cid`, same text content, both of those, or do you just want to keep the first `policy` regardless of their values)?  And finally, can you use XSLT 2.0 or are you limited to 1.0 (please add the appropriate tag to the question)?

Comment: And please search "*xsl remove duplicate*" on SO, there are tons of issues like this...